# BottomNavigationView with Navigation Editor facing issue of fragment not changing

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I am trying to use BottomNavigationView with Navigation Editor. I have implemented everything as given but only home page is showing, when I change the tab, it does not change the fragment.

This is the main activity code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    BottomNavigationView mainBottomNavigation;

    NavController navController;
    NavHostFragment navHostFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mainBottomNavigation = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(mainBottomNavigation, Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.nav_host_fragment));
    } }
```

This is the main activity xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the menu file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_location"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_location" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_sightseeing"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_sightseeing" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_gallery" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_contact_us"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_contact_us" />

</menu>
```

This is the nav_graph I have created :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/navigation_home">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_location"
        android:name="com.wedding.rashmilind.HomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_location"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_location" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_sightseeing"
        android:name="com.wedding.rashmilind.HomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_sightseeing"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_sight_seeing" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="com.wedding.rashmilind.HomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_gallery"
        android:name="com.wedding.rashmilind.HomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_gallery"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_gallery" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_contact_us"
        android:name="com.wedding.rashmilind.HomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_contact_us"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_contact_us" />
</navigation>
```

Comment: Have you setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener() on mainBottomNavigation?

Comment: but in using navigation editor we don't need this listner i Guess.

Comment: that's right, try using `view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.xyz)` for navigating

Comment: NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(mainBottomNavigation,
                Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.nav_host_fragment)); this line should do the trick and handle the clicks right? according to my understanding.

Comment: According to official documentation, this will call `onNavDestinationSelected(MenuItem, NavController)` when a menu item is selected. The selected item in the BottomNavigationView will automatically be updated when the destination changes.

This means that calling `setupWithNavController()` will keep the bottom navigation updated with the view/fragment showing, but wont change/navigate the actual view.

Comment: @ParthAnjaria Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

For navigating, you need to call NavController's **`navigate()`** method.

---

Navigating to a destination is done using a `NavController`, an object that manages app navigation within a `NavHost`. Each NavHost has its own corresponding NavController.

To retrieve the NavController for a fragment, activity, or view, use one of the following methods:

```
NavHostFragment.findNavController(Fragment)
// -- or --
Navigation.findNavController(Activity, @IdRes int viewId)
// -- or --
Navigation.findNavController(View)
```

Once you retrieve a NavController, use its `navigate()` method to navigate to a destination. The navigate() method accepts a resource ID of either an action or a destination.

Then, set the following on your navigation button's `onClick` :

```
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.viewTransactionsAction);
```

Reference : [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#navigate_to_a_destination)

Comment: The question is different. He uses tabs (that are defined in a separate xml file) in his application. Pressing tab buttons should perform fragment changing. But nothing happens. I am facing the same issue.